# How to draw a rectangle with round end circle corners using XML like Sticker View Corner

Tags: android, xml

How to create round circle for the rectangle edges like `StickerView` Have.
I don't want to use `StickerView`, because it does not support `EditText` like function.

My `xml` code for Rectangle. I would like to add Corners with round big dots.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">

        <corners

            android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>

    </shape>
```

Below is the `mainactivity.xml` code where I implement the borders for  `RotatableAutofitEditText`.

```
 <com.agilie.RotatableAutofitEditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"


            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="128dp"


            android:layout_marginTop="272dp"
            android:background="@drawable/borders"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/hint_add_some_text"
            android:text="Type Here"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            autofit:clipBounds="false"
            autofit:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            autofit:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            autofit:maxTextSize="@dimen/autoresize_max_text_size"
            autofit:minTextSize="@dimen/autoresize_min_text_size"
            autofit:minWidth="@dimen/autoresize_min_width"
            autofit:movable="true"
            autofit:resizable="true"
            autofit:rotatable="true" />
```

Comment: can you post image which shape you want to show?

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYUst.png

@Aniruddh Parihar.

I want xml code for this type of change through which I can scale and rotate my Edit Text.

Comment: this view is not possible with xml, instead of xml use image file as a background.

Answer (score 0):

A list of Github link for `StickerView`

1. https://github.com/nimengbo/StickerView
2. https://github.com/kencheung4/android-StickerView
3. https://github.com/uptechteam/MotionViews-Android
4. https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView
5. https://github.com/sangmingming/StickerView
6. https://github.com/niravkalola/Android-StickerView
7. https://github.com/Kaka252/StickerView
8. https://github.com/yovenny/StickerView

https://github.com/lukehutch/android-multitouch-controller
This handles 3 in 1 facility. On Multi-Touch, you can pan your image, you can scale your image and at the same time you can also rotate your image. And you can add number of stickers as you want.

Comment: I already mentioned that I want editing like edit View not like sticker VIew

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this template with your colors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="8dp"
    android:end="8dp"
    android:start="8dp"
    android:top="8dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:gravity="start|top">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size
            android:width="16dp"
            android:height="16dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:gravity="end|top">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size
            android:width="16dp"
            android:height="16dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:gravity="start|bottom">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size
            android:width="16dp"
            android:height="16dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:gravity="end|bottom">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size
            android:width="16dp"
            android:height="16dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: This is not the shape that I want I want to have like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYUst.png

Comment: As i mentioned its a template for you. Replace top end and bottom end corners with drawables you want. Also Replace solid with stroke in first item element.